# jQuery Sortable without jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I am in need of "Sortable Drag & Drop" functionality and I'm using jQuery. I can't really use jQuery UI, because for this project it would be an overhead (I'd need to add many KB of JS and CSS only to use small part of functionality).

Is there any plugin that you could recommend or maybe a simple implementation path, that I can follow?

*The solution must be as lightweight as possible, preferably based on jQuery/Sizzle or pure JavaScript.*

Comment: http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/ 2014 I think would be better solution

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can build your own JQuery download on jqueryui.com without all the css/theme information. You can also strip out the widgets and effects and just use draggable/droppable.

Comes to about 30KB all in. Still too large?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is. For the functionality required it is just way too much :-(

Comment: in the end had to use jquery.ui - other plugins are just not mature enough, so things like sorting within positioned (relative/absolute/fixed) parent or sorting heavily styled elements work too bugy. unfortunately for this project timescale doesn't let to dig into all the problems and rewrite these other plugins.

Comment: I looked at quite a few of them eg those listed in [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435051/drag-and-drop-without-jquery-ui) and came to the same conclusion. Esp for droppable (which I needed more than sortable) and a combination of things like revert to location if not dropped correctly, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure not using a customized, minified and gzipped version jQueryUI which you can maintain and update...

...maybe one of the plugins from the following blog post fits your favor:

"17 jQuery Plugins for Easy and Efficient Reordering and Filtering Page Elements"
http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2010/03/17-jquery-plugins-for-easy-and-efficient-reordering-and-filtering-page-elements.html

examples from the blogpost: "List Reorder" (<10KB) or "Sortable table rows with jQuery – Draggable rows" (<3KB)

Comment: Hey! Haven't find this list myself. I am now trying to rewrite "ListReorder" to support "sorting" for any block-line elements. Will update about that soon.

Comment: for simple sorting, though, if you don't have positioned parents or heavy styling on sorted elements, this list-reorder is pretty ok.

Comment: nice to know for further scripting...  jQuery mobile grows insanely when adding jQueryUI to it...

Comment: btw, that's where I've got editing list-reorder plugin, although not finished: http://jsfiddle.net/gryzzly/L6Upf/

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [jQuery UI source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/zipball/1.8.7), `jquery.ui.sortable.js` is a separate file, which I believe depends only on `jquery.ui.core.js`, `jquery.ui.widget.js` and `jquery.ui.mouse.js`, although I haven't tested this. However, this still weighs in at 36KB minified.

Answer (score 1):

You can try mine (http://jsfiddle.net/606bs750/16/).
Unlimited number of blocks you can drag and sort.

Blocks will constrain to the parent.

```
<div id="parent" class="parent">
    <button id="button1" class="button">Drag me 1</button>
    <button id="button2" class="button">Drag me 2</button>
    <button id="button3" class="button">Drag me 3</button>
    <button id="button4" class="button">Drag me 4</button>
</div>
```

JQuery (only):

```
$(function() {
    $('.button').mousedown(function(e) {
        if(e.which===1) {
            var button = $(this);
            var button_id = button.attr('id');
            var parent_height = button.parent().innerHeight();
            var top = parseInt(button.css('top'));
            var original_ypos = button.position().top; //original ypos
            var drag_min_ypos = 0-original_ypos;
            var drag_max_ypos = parent_height-original_ypos-button.outerHeight();
            var drag_start_ypos = e.clientY;
            var my_ypos = original_ypos;
            //Set current order for all
            $('.button').each(function(i) { $(this).attr('data-order',(i+1)); });
            var prev_button = button.prev('.button'); var next_button = button.next('.button');
            var prev_button_ypos = prev_button.length>0 ? prev_button.position().top : '';
            var next_button_ypos = next_button.length>0 ? next_button.position().top : '';
            $('#log1').text('mousedown '+button_id+' original_ypos: '+original_ypos);
            $('#log2').text('');
            $('#log3').text('');
            $(window).on('mousemove',function(e) {
                //Move and constrain
                button.addClass('drag');
                var direction = my_ypos>button.position().top ? 'up' : 'down';
                var new_top = top+(e.clientY-drag_start_ypos);
                my_ypos = button.position().top;
                button.css({top:new_top+'px'});
                if(new_top<drag_min_ypos) { button.css({top:drag_min_ypos+'px'}); }
                if(new_top>drag_max_ypos) { button.css({top:drag_max_ypos+'px'}); }
                $('#log2').text('mousemove new_top: '+new_top+', my_ypos: '+my_ypos+', direction: '+direction);
                //$('#log3').text('');
                //Check position over others
                if(direction=='down'&&next_button_ypos!='') {
                    if(my_ypos>next_button_ypos) { //crossed next button
                        $('#log3').text('dragged after '+next_button_ypos+' ('+next_button.attr('id')+')');
                        next_button.css({top:(parseInt(next_button.css('top'))-next_button.outerHeight(true))+'px'}); //up once
                        var tmp_order = next_button.attr('data-order');
                        next_button.attr('data-order',button.attr('data-order')); //switch order
                        button.attr('data-order',tmp_order);
                        prev_button = next_button; next_button = next_button.nextAll('.button:not(.drag)').first();
                        prev_button_ypos = prev_button.length>0 ? prev_button.position().top : '';
                        next_button_ypos = next_button.length>0 ? next_button.position().top : '';
                    }
                } else if(direction=='up'&&prev_button_ypos!='') {
                    if(my_ypos<prev_button_ypos) { //crossed prev button
                        $('#log3').text('dragged before '+prev_button_ypos+', '+prev_button.attr('id'));
                        prev_button.css({top:(parseInt(prev_button.css('top'))+prev_button.outerHeight(true))+'px'}); //down once
                        var tmp_order = prev_button.attr('data-order');
                        prev_button.attr('data-order',button.attr('data-order')); //switch order
                        button.attr('data-order',tmp_order);
                        next_button = prev_button; prev_button = prev_button.prevAll('.button:not(.drag)').first();
                        prev_button_ypos = prev_button.length>0 ? prev_button.position().top : '';
                        next_button_ypos = next_button.length>0 ? next_button.position().top : '';
                    }
                }
                $('#log4').text('prev_button_ypos: '+prev_button_ypos+' ('+prev_button.attr('id')+'), next_button_ypos: '+next_button_ypos+' ('+next_button.attr('id')+')');
            });
            $(window).on('mouseup',function(e) {
                 if(e.which===1) {
                    $('.button').removeClass('drag');
                    $(window).off('mouseup mousemove');
                    //Reorder and reposition all
                    $('.button').each(function() {
                        var this_order = parseInt($(this).attr('data-order'));
                        var prev_order = $(this).siblings('.button[data-order="'+(this_order-1)+'"]');
                        if(prev_order.length>0) { $(this).insertAfter(prev_order); }
                    });
                    $('.button').css('top','0'); $('.button').removeAttr('data-order'); //reset
                    $('#log1').text('mouseup');
                    $('#log2').text('');
                    $('#log3').text('');
                    $('#log4').text('');
                 }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Jason, I think if you add 'touchstart', 'touchmove' and 'touchend' alongside 'mousedown', 'mousemove' and 'mouseup', then it should work. The touch positions might use another variable other than e.clientX and e.clientY, so you may need to scour StackOverflow for those variables if they don't work straight-away. Testing is the key to get it working on touch. You may have to change $('.button').mousedown(funciton(e) { to use jquery's on handler $('.button').on('mousedown touchstart', function(e) {. You might also need jquery.ui or jquery.mobile to support those touch events I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you go for "LMDD drag and drop"
Less than 4kb gzipped and very simple to implement.
https://supraniti.github.io/Lean-Mean-Drag-and-Drop/
Simple example:

```
div id="basic-example"> (scope)
    <div class="grid"> (container)
        <div class="item"></div> (draggable)
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    lmdd.set(document.getElementById('basic-example'), {
        containerClass: 'grid',
        draggableItemClass: 'item'
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is it sortable too?

Comment: Yes. You can sort and reorder hymn elements

Answer (score 0):

theres one here http://plugins.jquery.com/project/NestedSortable
it doesnt use UI, and is only 5kb(although you could hack any extra functionality to get it down lower if needed)

hope that helps

Andrew

Comment: that one depends on http://interface.eyecon.ro/ which is more than 100k by itself :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want no frills one then I found this one the best:
http://jsfiddle.net/erikdana/Nkykq/3/    upto
http://jsfiddle.net/erikdana/Nkykq/6/

very very light and up to the point.

**js**

```
$('#box').bind({
    mousedown: function() {
        $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
            $('#box').css({
                top: e.pageY - 10,
                left: e.pageX - 20
            });
        });
    },
    mouseup: function() {
        $(document).unbind(mousedown);
        var box = $('#box').css('top');
        if (box > '100') {
            $('#box').css({width: '100px'});
        };
    }
});
```

**css**

```
div {width:50px;height:50px;background:blue;position:absolute; cursor:move;}
div:focus { cursor:move;}
```

Comment: That's a neat script for *draggable* capabilities, but the question is about *sortable*, which is way more than just moving items around.