# Simple range /value Slider in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, mouseevent

I am trying to do a simple Range/Value Slider by using `javascript` or `jQuery`, A `button` in a `div`.This slider should be done without `bootstrap`or any other `plugin`or with `inbuild functions`

My question is how to move the slider button within the div element and what `mouse events` are needed to do this?

Note:This is not a slideshow slider or image slider

Comment: inbuild functions. do you mean not using Dragable and Dropable?

Comment: Yes,I mean not to use jQueryUI. but javascript functions can be used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this simple slider implementation. Feel free to use and modify the way you prefer:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.my-slider');

  [].forEach.call(sliders, function(el, i) {
    var btn = el.firstElementChild,
        span = el.nextElementSibling.querySelector('span'),
        isMoving = false;
    
    var move = function(e) {
      if (isMoving) {
        var min = 0,
            max = el.offsetWidth - btn.offsetWidth,
            mousePos = (e.pageX - el.offsetLeft - (btn.offsetWidth / 2)),
            position = (mousePos > max ? max : mousePos < min ? min : mousePos),
            value = Math.floor((position / max) * 100);        

        btn.style.marginLeft = position + 'px';
        btn.value = value;
        span.textContent = value;
      }
    };
    
    el.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
      isMoving = true;
      move(e);
    });

    document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
      isMoving = false;
    });

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
      move(e);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.my-slider {
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 10px;
  line-height: 10px;
}
.my-slider__button {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: -4px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  background-color: #eee;
  display: block;
}

div {
  margin-top: 6px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="my-slider">
  <button class="my-slider__button"></button>
</div>
<div>
  <strong>Current value: </strong><span></span>
</div>
<div class="my-slider">
  <button class="my-slider__button"></button>
</div>
<div>
  <strong>Current value: </strong><span></span>
</div>
<div class="my-slider">
  <button class="my-slider__button"></button>
</div>
<div>
  <strong>Current value: </strong><span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Tested on lastest versions of Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and IE11/10/9. Tested on IE8 either, but it didn't pass (no `addEventListener` support, nor `event.pageX`, nor `Array.prototype.forEach`). If you need to support IE8, you must grab some polyfills to make it work.

Comment: What is the latest version properties and functions equivalent for the older one's

Answer (score 2):

You use drag and drop events, with a property setting that is restricted to the div it is within.  Check out this link [Drag Drop Reference Guide](http://www.elated.com/articles/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/), and you will see everything you need. When you use draggable and dropable, you can restrict the movement to horizontal, and also set the element that it is bound to. This will allow you to only move left to right, and restrict vertical movement, and keep in the boundaries of the div. The same features bootstrap uses to get it done.

Here is a basic example showing some of the stuff mentioned:

```
     $('. draggable').draggable({
    axis: 'y',
    handle: '.top'
    drag: function( event, ui ) {
       var distance = ui.originalPosition.top - ui.position.top;

       // if dragged towards top
       if (distance > 0) { 
           //then set it to its initial state
           $('.draggable').css({top: ui.originalPosition.top + 'px'});
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank You,But is there any option to do it in javascript or jquery without using jqueryUi

Comment: That my friend, I would not know off hand. I would need to research it. Anything like that, I use thier pre disposed libraries, instead of reinventing the wheel. UNLESS i am doing it for researchon my behalf, and see how they handle it. Maybe look at the source for jQuery UI methods, and get an idea from there on how to handle it.

Comment: There is a great post about this very same topic basically, that has an explanation in pure js. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11961845/2762516

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
  $('img').mouseenter(function(){ //or you can use hover()
   // Set the effect type
    var effect = 'slide';

     // Set the options for the effect type chosen
    var options = { direction: "right" };

   // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
    var duration = 1000;

    $(this).toggle(effect, options, duration);
   });
```

Comment: please accept the answer if you are satisfied with this :)

Comment: The above example is similar to your answer,it works good.But i am looking for javascript/jquery. is there any slideRight method in js